# Angular Js ngGrid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

all, i need to conditionally show a hyperlink(ng-href) in a ngGrid column based on a value in the json.

for example if the age is > 18 for a person in the grid, show them the "BuyBeer" link. else show a string, "not yet mate"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to redefine the cell template for this, something on the lines of

```
columnDefs: [

     {
         field:'buy', displayName:'Buy', 
         cellTemplate: '<div><a ng-if='row.getProperty('age')>18' href='{{row.getProperty('hyperlink')}}'>Buy</a><span ng-if='row.getProperty('age')<18'>Not Yet<span></div>'}]
     };
```

Look at template examples in the ng-grid documentation http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/.

Comment: IF you find the answer useful up vote it, or mark it correct if it worked.